# How to save List<Model> on onSaveInstaceState and retrieve it in onRestoreInstanceState

Tags: android

I have a list that I want to store it after binding it with data so that when a user rotate the device, it won't have to download the data on the server.

Here is the Model

```
public class Model {
String Id, Name, Work, Phone, Lp;

public String getId() {
    return Id;
}

public String getLp() {
    return Lp;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return Phone;
}

public String getWork() {
    return Work;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    Id = id;
}

public void setLp(String lp) {
    Lp = lp;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    Phone = phone;
}

public void setWork(String work) {
    Work = work;
}
}
```

so, how to I implement the onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState?
Any help please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` use `Bundle` for the data transfer. Bundle don't support too many ways to store a list of data. The only one which could apply to your needs would be [`putParcelableArrayList()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelableArrayList(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E)).

For this you need to implement [`Parcelable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) with your `Model` and in `onSaveInstanceState()` you wrap the generic list with an `ArrayList` to put the data:

```
outState.putParcelableArrayList(new ArrayList<Model>(models))
```

Retrieving the models again from a bundle is straightforward.